# how to replace + in javascript?

Tags: javascript

How to replace character '+' in string with unicode?

```
E.G.
  Before replace -> "table+end"
  After replace -> "table002Bend"
```

I tried using

```
  tableName.replace(/+/g,"002B);
```

but browser running the JS is throwing the error stating:

> *Invalid identifier*

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to url encode a string incorrectly.

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape `+`, if you use it in regex. Try it this way:

```
tableName.replace(/\+/g,"002B")
```

Unescaped plus sign is the match-one-or-more quantifier.

Note that you don't even need regex for this simple replace.

Comment: The semi-colon at the end implies that the line is a stand-alone statement. Which it is *not* - it's just an expression.

Comment: It could even be that the OP is forgetting to assign this expression, e.g. `tableName = tableName.replace(...);` (String values are immutable so one has to explicitly assign the result of `replace()` (which is a *new* String value) to the variable).

Answer (score 2):

Two things: the `+` character has a special meaning in regular expressions, if you look at the error you get:

> SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /+/: Nothing to repeat

You see that `+` effectively means: *repeat the previous "part" of the expression*. You can use a backslash, to specify that you want to replace the literal `+` char (`/\+/`) *or* you can create a character class, wherein you don't need to escape all special chars: `/[+]/`.

After that, you might still have an error shown because of a missing string delimiter:

```
tableName.replace(/+/g,"002B);//<--missing closing "
```

All in all, either one of these should do the trick:

```
tableName.replace(/\+/g,"002B");
tableName.replace(/[+]/g,"002B");
```

If, however you want to *"url-encode"* a string, why not simply use `encodeURI(tableName)`?

Answer (score 1):

Using regex, the `+` has a special meaning in regex and needs to be escaped:

```
tableName = tableName.replace(/\+/g, '002B');
```

If you're just replacing a single `+`, you don't need regex:

```
tableName = tableName.replace('+', '002B');
```

However, the caveat with this is that it will only replace the first `+` encountered. A workaround to do a "quick" replace-all is to combine `split()` and `join()`:

```
tableName = tableName.split('+').join('002B');
```

Comment: unfortunately without the regex it will only replace the first `+`, not all of them.

Comment: this appears to be way faster than regex replace (on chrome, atleast) +1 http://jsperf.com/regex-or-split-join-for-replace